# How to read excel file and use it as a variable for different body in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I have a url. I have created 50 threads in jmeter. I want to post 50 different bodies to 50 different threads. The parameter that should be unique in each body is stored in an excel file, in 50 rows. For each body i want to use these 50 variables in excel sheet , one by one row wise. How can this be done?

Comment: If what's your looking for is to simply put each sheet row as a next thread parameter,  consider changing your sheet extension to .csv, and then answer given in this post would fit your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583619/read-excel-data-csv-file-sequentially-in-jmeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is realy **excel** (i.e. [xls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Binary) or [xlsx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet)) you can read them using i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library like described in the [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test) guide.

You should get variables like:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
var_3=baz
```

There are 2 ways of iterating the variables:

1. Using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

   [image]

   [image]
2. Using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination like `${__V(var_${__threadNum})}`

   [image]

---

However if you can control the Excel file it will be **much easier** [to save it as .csv](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/04/24/convert-excel-csv/) and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)